# jquery carousel, relative positioning and overflow

Tags: html, css, position, overflow

I am trying to add a carousel-like [animation](http://domjan.fizika.org/flash.html) to my photographic calculator
I am extremely new to javascript/html/css so I have been having some troubles doing this. :)

My idea was to fill in each table row with divs generated from an array, with all but the three divs beeing hidden by overflow:hidden of the outer container.
Here if my [test jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dsvilko/Wdnw9/17/):

```
table {
    width:80%;
    background:#ffff00;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.test {
    width:33.3333%;
    height:100%;
    background:cyan;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:center;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    left:0%;
    top: 0px;
}
```

The problem is if I try to add more than 3 divs (set n=4), they wrap to the next line while I want them to stay on the same line. If I use absolute positioning then I can't use the overflow hiding (or can I?).

I am hoping there is an easy solution to this. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `float: left` causes elements to wrap when filling all available horizontal space. What you need to do is arrange your divs inline and make elements in your carousel not wrap:

http://jsfiddle.net/Wdnw9/19/

### CSS

```css
#box { white-space: nowrap; }
.test{
    ...
    display: inline-block;
}
```